# Location of C header files in debian

Tags: c, linux, unix, debian, header-files

Where does debian stores C header files like `stdio.h`, `string.h` etc? I am working on a project and I need to add a header file to the location but I couldn't locate it anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried running `locate stdio.h` in you terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system headers are in `/usr/include` and the headers for user-installed packages are in `/usr/local/include`.

But you only should put headers there if you are writing a library which other projects will use.  Otherwise, you should use the `-I` flag for your compiler to specify the location of additional header file search paths.

Answer (score 2):

1. Typically in /usr/include
2. It wouldn't hurt to run a command like this to make sure you've got the "basics" like compiler and standard headers: `apt-get install build-essential`
3. Failing all else, you can also do a "find".  For example:

   `find / -name stdio.h -print 2> /dev/null`